# .NET MVC Model with class inside class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know the technical name but I'll explain.

I have a model named Project, that has a Name ,Description.

Each Project has multiple tasks.

What I have is something like this

MODEL

```
 public class Project
    {
        public String Namevm { get; set; }
        public String Descriptionvm { get; set; }

        public Tasks Taskvm { get; set; }

    }

 public class Task
    {
        public String Namevm { get; set; }
        public String Descriptionvm { get; set; }

    }
```

CONTROLER

```
        public ActionResult Report (int id)
        {
            Project Report= new Project();

            Report.Taskvm = from o in db.tasks
                            where o.project_id == id
                            select new Task { name = o.name, description=o.description };
 
            Report.Namevm = "NAME OF PROJECT";
            Report.Descriptionvm= "DESCRIPTION OF PROJECT";
            return View(Report);

        }
```

How can I print Report.Namevm and Report.Descriptionvm

And iterate all tasks ?

I've tried this but doesnt work

VIEW

```
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
          {
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taskvm.Namevm ) 
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taskvm.Descriptionvm) 
           <br>                                
        }
```

Comment: What is `relatorio`? It looks like you should be passing `Report` to the view...

Comment: sorry, its Report (another language).. i've updated the question

Comment: So, if `Model` is `Report`, and you want to iterate over `Report.Tasksvm`, you probably don't want to iterate over `Model`, but rather...?

Comment: well, ive tried with Model.Tasksvm and it shows 
Error CS1061 'IEnumerable<Project>' does not contain a definition for 'Project' and no accessible extension method 'Project' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Project>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So, apparently the `@model` on your page is `IEnumerable<Project>`? If that's the case, you'll need to change what you pass the `View()` to be an `IEnumerable<Project>`, rather than just `Project`, and `@foreach (var item in Model)` is fine, but you'll need another `foreach` over `Taskvm` within that, so `@foreach (var task in item.Taskvm)`.

Comment: so, in the controler i've put return View(IEnumerable<Report>) and now shows an error CS0119 'IEnumerable<Report>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Right, you need to pass something that implements `IEnumerable<Report>`... Use `new List<Project> { Report }` for now. Later, consider whether your page will be displaying one or multiple projects at once. If one, change the model to just `Project`. If more than one, be sure to get a list of reports from wherever you're keeping them. This comment chain is becoming overly long -- consider reading some more tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong?

1. Your Taskvm property cannot be iterated (you can't loop through it).
2. The query string is not getting a list but a single object.
3. You are not looping through the right property in your view.

To fix all this:

1. Update your Project model, **the Taskvm property**.

   ```
    public class Project
    {
        public String Namevm { get; set; }
        public String Descriptionvm { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Tasks> Taskvm { get; set; }
    }
   ```

The IEnumerable<> will need the below namespace

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

2. In your controller, change your query to this **note the ToList()**:

   ```
   Report.Taskvm = (from o in db.tasks
                            where o.project_id == id
                            select new Task { name = o.name, description=o.description })
                            .ToList();
   ```
3. In your view, you need to iterate the **Taskvm (Model.Taskvm)** property, not the whole model. Use this:

   ```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Taskvm) 
      {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Namevm ) 
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descriptionvm) 
       <br />                                
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. 5 stars!!! With that Light in my head. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet of code

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taskvm.Namevm ) 
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taskvm.Descriptionvm) 
       <br>                                
}
```

And your request

> How can I print Report.Namevm and Report.Descriptionvm

The `Model` is an instance of the `Project`class.

Please change the property `Taskvm` from `Tasks`to `IEnumerable<Task>` (or at least define the `Tasks` like a wrapper of a list.
In this way you can iterate with something like the posted snippet.

Iterate throug the Tasksvm `IEnumerable`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tasksvm) 
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Namevm ) 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taskvm.Descriptionvm) 
   <br>           
                                      
}
```